# German language is not showing in php with utf-8 or ISO-8859-1?

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to show some german content in my PHP project **but ä is showing as �** , **word  - Termine 2022 abhängig von Sicherheitslage** is showing in MySQL database but on web page is is showing as **Termine 2022 abh�ngig von Sicherheitslage**

**Values are coming from MYSQL database**

I have tried to use some encoding in header too.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

But nothing works

Comment: Where is this value coming from? Database? User input? Somewhere else?

Comment: values coming from database

Comment: See if this helps: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

Comment: Don't know if dieresis are included in ISO-8859-1. Anyway, what is your db, tables and field encoding? Are all declared as ISO-8859-1?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer and consideration I solved my issue with

```
// Create connection
$conn= mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (!$conn->set_charset("utf8")) {
 printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $conn->error);
 } else {
  printf("Current character set: %s\n", $conn->character_set_name());
}
```

Comment: Does this mean `set_charset( 'utf8' )` is what you missed?